# Installation of cmake 2.8.11 on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: cmake

I tried to install cmake 2.8.11 on Ubuntu 13.04. I got cmake 2.8.11 source and during installing some errors happened. And Ubuntu installs  cmake 2.8.10. Because of a lot of dependencies I am not able to install manually. Please suggest how I can install cmake 2.8.11 on Ubuntu 13.04.

---

I use a open source code, needs cmake 2.8.11 for accurate execution. I tried to install 
by the following commands:

```
tar -xzvf cmake-2.8.11.2.tar.gz
cd cmake-2.8.11.2.tar.gz
./configure
make
```

after  `./configure`:

```
-- Checking whether C++ compiler has '__int64' - no

-- Checking for C type size macros

-- Checking for C type size macros - compiled

-- Looking for sys/types.h

-- Check size of __int64 - failed

-- Checking whether char is signed

-- Checking whether CXX compiler has _atoi64 - no

-- Looking for connect in socket;dl

-- Looking for connect in socket;dl - not found

-- Looking for gethostbyname in c

-- Looking for gethostbyname in c - found

-- Looking for recv in network;dl

-- Looking for recv in network;dl - not found

-- Looking for getch in ws2_32;dl

-- Looking for getch in ws2_32;dl - not found

-- Looking for getch in winmm;dl

-- Looking for getch in winmm;dl - not found

-- Looking for idna_to_ascii_lz in idn;dl

-- Looking for idna_to_ascii_lz in idn;dl - not found

-- Looking for dlopen in dl

-- Looking for dlopen in dl - found

-- Looking for process.h

-- Looking for process.h - not found

-- Looking for features.h

-- Looking for features.h - found

-- Looking for include file stdio.h

-- Looking for 37 include files stdio.h, ..., sys/utime.h - not found

-- Looking for 37 include files stdio.h, ..., sockio.h

-- Looking for 37 include files stdio.h, ..., sockio.h - not found

-- Looking for 37 include files stdio.h, ..., sys/sockio.h

-- Looking for 37 include files stdio.h, ..., sys/sockio.h - not found

-- Looking for 37 include files stdio.h, ..., x509.h

-- Looking for 37 include files stdio.h, ..., x509.h - not found

-- Looking for 42 include files stdio.h, ..., idn-free.h - not found

-- Looking for 42 include files stdio.h, ..., idna.h

-- Looking for 42 include files stdio.h, ..., idna.h - not found

-- Looking for 42 include files stdio.h, ..., tld.h - not found

-- Looking for 45 include files stdio.h, ..., sys/filio.h - not found

-- Check size of __int64 - failed

-- Looking for stricmp - not found

-- Looking for strcmpi

-- Looking for strcmpi - not found

-- Looking for strncmpi

-- Looking for strncmpi - not found

-- Looking for inet_ntoa_r - not found

-- Looking for closesocket

-- Looking for closesocket - not found

-- Looking for getpass_r - not found

-- Looking for _strtoi64 - not found

-- Looking for strerror_r

-- Looking for idn_free - not found

-- Looking for idna_strerror

-- Looking for idna_strerror - not found

-- Looking for tld_strerror

-- Looking for tld_strerror - not found

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_FIONBIO - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CASE

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CASE - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_O_NONBLOCK

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_O_NONBLOCK - Success

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SO_NONBLOCK

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SO_NONBLOCK - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME

-- Performing Curl Test TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME - Success

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_O_NONBLOCKHAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_5

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_O_NONBLOCKHAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_5 - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_7

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_7 - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_8

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_8 - Success

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_5_REENTRANT

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_5_REENTRANT - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_7_REENTRANT

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_7_REENTRANT - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_8_REENTRANT

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYADDR_R_8_REENTRANT - Success

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3 - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5 - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6 

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6 - Success

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_REENTRANT

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_REENTRANT - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_REENTRANT

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_REENTRANT - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_REENTRANT

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_INET_NTOA_R_DECL - Failed

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_INET_NTOA_R_DECL_REENTRANT

-- Performing Curl Test HAVE_INET_NTOA_R_DECL_REENTRANT - Failed

-- Check size of curl_off_t - done

-- Performing Test curl_cv_recv

-- Performing Test curl_cv_recv - Success

-- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - 
Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)
 - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(int, char *, unsigned int, unsigned int) 
(curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)
-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed


-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)
 - Failed

Failed

(curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)
 - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed


-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)
 - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(ssize_t, char *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, socklen_t, unsigned int) 
(curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, socklen_t, unsigned int) 
(curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) 
- Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) 
(curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, size_t, unsigned int) 
(curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)


-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)

-- Performing Test int recv(SOCKET, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test curl_cv_send

-- Performing Test curl_cv_send - Success

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, void *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, socklen_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, unsigned int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, char *, unsigned int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, size_t, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, int, unsigned int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Performing Test int send(int, const char *, socklen_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(SOCKET, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test)

-- Performing Test int send(SOCKET, char *, int, int) (curl_cv_func_send_test) - Failed

-- Found ZLIB: cmzlib  

-- Found BZip2: cmbzip2 (found version "1.0.5") 

-- Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit in cmbzip2

-- Looking for BZ2_bzCompressInit in cmbzip2 - not found

-- Performing Test HAVE_DIRENT_H

-- Performing Test HAVE_DIRENT_H - Success

-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, acl/libacl.h

-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, acl/libacl.h - not found

-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, ctype.h

-- Looking for include files sys/types.h, ctype.h - found

-- Looking for 3 include files sys/types.h, ..., copyfile.h

-- Looking for 3 include files sys/types.h, ..., copyfile.h - not found

-- Looking for 3 include files sys/types.h, ..., direct.h

-- Looking for 3 include files sys/types.h, ..., direct.h - not found

-- Looking for 5 include files sys/types.h, ..., ext2fs/ext2_fs.h

-- Looking for 5 include files sys/types.h, ..., ext2fs/ext2_fs.h - not found

-- Performing Test HAVE_WORKING_EXT2_IOC_GETFLAGS

-- Performing Test HAVE_WORKING_EXT2_IOC_GETFLAGS - Failed

-- Looking for 26 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/acl.h

-- Looking for 26 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/acl.h - not found

-- Looking for 26 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/cdefs.h

-- Looking for 26 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/cdefs.h - found

-- Looking for 28 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/mkdev.h

-- Looking for 28 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/mkdev.h - not found

-- Looking for 28 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/mount.h

-- Looking for 28 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/mount.h - not found

-- Looking for 32 include files sys/types.h, ..., sys/statfs.h

-- Looking for 43 include files sys/types.h, ..., windows.h - not found

-- Looking for 43 include files sys/types.h, ..., wincrypt.h

-- Looking for 43 include files sys/types.h, ..., wincrypt.h - not found

-- Looking for 43 include files sys/types.h, ..., winioctl.h

-- Looking for 43 include files sys/types.h, ..., winioctl.h - not found

-- Performing Test SAFE_TO_DEFINE_EXTENSIONS

-- Performing Test SAFE_TO_DEFINE_EXTENSIONS - Success

-- Looking for MD5Init in md

-- Looking for MD5Init in md - not found

-- Looking for _CrtSetReportMode

-- Looking for _CrtSetReportMode - not found

-- Looking for chown

-- Looking for getpid

-- Looking for getpid - found

-- Looking for getvfsbyname

-- Looking for getvfsbyname - not found

-- Looking for lchflags

-- Looking for lchflags - not found

-- Looking for strncpy_s

-- Looking for strncpy_s - not found

-- Looking for _ctime64_s - not found

-- Looking for _fseeki64

-- Looking for _fseeki64 - not found

-- Looking for _get_timezone

-- Looking for _get_timezone - not found

-- Looking for _localtime64_s

-- Looking for _localtime64_s - not found

-- Looking for _mkgmtime64

-- Looking for _mkgmtime64 - not found

-- Looking for cygwin_conv_path

-- Looking for cygwin_conv_path - not found

-- Performing Test MAJOR_IN_MKDEV - Failed

-- Looking for EFTYPE

-- Looking for EFTYPE - not found

-- Looking for EILSE

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TM___TM_GMTOFF

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TM___TM_GMTOFF - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STATFS_F_NAMEMAX

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STATFS_F_NAMEMAX - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIME

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIME - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM_TV_NSEC

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM_TV_NSEC - Success

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIME_N

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIME_N - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_UMTIME

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_UMTIME - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIME_USEC

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIME_USEC - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLKSIZE

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLKSIZE - Success

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_FLAGS

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_FLAGS - Failed

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STATVFS_F_IOSIZE

-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STATVFS_F_IOSIZE - Failed

-- Checking _FILE_OFFSET_BITS for large files

-- Checking _FILE_OFFSET_BITS for large files - not needed

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBC

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBC -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBC

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBC -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBC

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBC -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC2

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC2 -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC2

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC2 -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC2

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC2 -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC3

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBC3 -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC3

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBC3 -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC3

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBC3 -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBSYSTEM

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBSYSTEM -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBSYSTEM

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBSYSTEM -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBSYSTEM

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBSYSTEM -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBSYSTEM

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA384_LIBSYSTEM -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBSYSTEM

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBSYSTEM -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBMD

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_MD5_LIBMD -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBMD

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_RMD160_LIBMD -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBMD

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA1_LIBMD -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBMD

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA256_LIBMD -- not found

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBMD

-- Checking support for ARCHIVE_CRYPTO_SHA512_LIBMD -- not found

-- Check if the system is big endian

-- Searching 16 bit integer

-- Check size of unsigned short

-- Check size of unsigned short - done

-- Using unsigned short

-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian

-- Looking for elf.h

-- Looking for elf.h - found

-- Looking for a Fortran compiler

-- Looking for a Fortran compiler - /usr/bin/f95

-- Looking for Q_WS_X11

-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found

-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN

-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found

-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS

-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found

-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC

-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found

-- Found unsuitable Qt version "5.0.1" from /usr/bin/qmake

-- Performing Test run_pic_test

-- Performing Test run_pic_test - Success

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---------------------------------------------

Error when bootstrapping CMake:

Problem while running initial CMake

---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please *modify* your question to include: Why do you need 2.8.11 and why is 2.8.10.1 in the repository not good enough for you? If you really really need .11 then include all specific errors you get on installing. Use Copy&Paste - keep in mind that we can't see your screen so we rely on all information you provide in your question.

Answer (score 3):

### Package Information

- Download (HTTP): http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
- Download MD5 sum: be6008f2299613d23fe82ab53ef7472e (see [How To MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM))

### CMake Dependencies

- **Required**: [**cURL-7.31.0**](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/curl.html), [**libarchive-3.1.2**](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libarchive.html) and [**expat-2.1.0**](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/expat.html) (so, first you must to be sure that you have these packages installed)
- Optional: [Subversion-1.8.0](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/subversion.html) (for testing) and [Qt-4.8.4](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/qt4.html) (for the Qt-based GUI)

### Installation of CMake

Install CMake by running the following commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```bsh
cd <DOWNLOADS-DIRECTORY>
md5sum cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz        #optional, to check MD5 sum
tar -xzvf cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
cd cmake-2.8.11
./bootstrap --prefix=/usr --system-libs --mandir=/share/man --docdir=/share/doc/cmake-2.8.11
make
make test                         #optional, to test the results
sudo make install
```

Source: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/cmake.html.